# how to serialize double value both as primitive type and null value using jackson api

Tags: java, jackson

I am using Jackson api for serialization and deserialization. My application is low latency application, so my target is  to avoid creation of objects.

For class :

```
Class Quote {
int instrument;
Double bidPrice;
}
```

It works fine if valid bidPrice or null is present for quotes and serialization or deserialization works fine.

However, java is creating lot of objects using Double.valueOf due to autoconversion.

I tried using ObjectPool concept using MutableDouble , so that it returns the double value or null value. however, while assigning the types, It again reverts to same problem of : Double.valueOF.

In summary, how I can serialize or deserialize double value as NULL or valid value without creating wrapper objects.

Please note that I am fine to create initial set of objects for storing values ,and can not change the contract due to external vendor protocol.

any suggestions related to this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: _"java is creating lot of objects using Double.valueOf "_ -- how do you know this?  You say you can't change the contract, does that mean you can't change `Double` to `double` in the `Quote` class?

Comment: @JimGarrison I profiled my application using yourkit and found out the cause. I can not change contract, but i can change Double bidPRice to double bidPrice or add booleanf lag to indicate whether it is null or not. However, in the end it should serilaze it as either null or permittive value

Comment: Changing the variables changes the contract. But why would the bid price in a quote ever be null?